# Connection notification to resume NSOperationQueue

Tags: iphone, nsoperation, nsnotifications, nsoperationqueue

I need to download some images from the Internet and right now I'm using `NSOperationQueue`.

I want to know if it is possible to receive an Internet connection notification to be able to pause/resume the download.

I don't need to freeze the download, but just being able to put it (the `NSOperation`) back on the queue and wait for connection to start it again would be awesome.

Any ideas?
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking for reachability, you can set the NSOperationQueue length to 0 if it's not reachable. That way you can effectively pause it.

Comment: Hi, I like your idea. I'll try it later today.

Answer (score 1):

See this link for further help. You could use the code with apple documentation listed.
WAN detection and airport detection is shown in the code.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html